# Javascript - Abrindo nova janela com nova aba

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boa noite, gostaria de saber se é possível abrir um nova janela, com o método `window.open();`, e uma nova aba nessa janela criada ?

Tudo isso em Javascript, jQuery ou HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:novaJanela('https://www.google.com')">Clique aqui para abrir</a>

<script>
    function novaJanela (URL){
        window.open(URL,"janela1","width=800, height=600, directories=no, location=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no, status=no, toolbar=no, resizable=no")
    }
</script>
```